# Azure Runbook Powershell move zip file from Blob Container to FileShare and Unzip the file once in destination

Tags: azure, powershell, zip, archive, expand

I am trying to move zip files from an Azure Blob container to an Azure fileShare.  I want to add in the option to unzip the file on the destination side.  I am using Powershell in an automation runbook.  The following is a snippit from my function.  I have not been able to figure out the Expand-Archive cmdlet where all activity is taking place in storage accounts (no local path c:\, etc)

```
            if ($blob.name.StartsWith($blobMatch)) {
                $destFile
                $blobName = $blob.name
                #Get-AzureStorageFileContent
                #Expand-Archive -Path $blob -DestinationPath $destFile
                Start-AzureStorageFileCopy `
                    -SrcBlobName $blob.name `
                    -SrcContainerName $sourceContainer `
                    -DestShareName $destinationShare `
                    -DestFilePath $destFile `
                    -Context $ctx `
                    -DestContext $ctx `
                    -Force
```

}

Comment: Any update this issue? If my reply is helpful, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to unzip the file in storage file share, you can put there zipped content, but you can't make the Storage Service unzip it. The workaround is downloading the file first, then unzip it.

Here is a similar issue, you could refer to [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/483b5895-0fa2-4a14-995a-5b508af392f4/can-i-unzip-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage).